# Copy file to docker image in LCOW

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to try out some of the LCOW stuff for docker, so I attempted to build an image based off of redis:4.0.8-alpine. I have a custom sentinel.conf file I need to copy over to the image. When Docker gets to the copy step, I get this error:

```
invalid COPY: Current WorkingDir / is not platform consistent
```

Here is my dockerfile

```
# Set the base image
FROM redis:4.0.8-alpine
WORKDIR /

# Copy over the configuration file
COPY sentinel.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/sentinel.conf
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

# Copy over the entrypoint that sets the environment variables
COPY redis-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

# Set the entrypoint to the new entrypoint script
# this script calls the original entrypoint when configuration file is ready
ENTRYPOINT ["redis-entrypoint.sh"]

# Define the entry point for the image
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Any idea how I can make my working dir platform consistent?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue
    `FROM redis:4.0.8-alpine
    WORKDIR /
    COPY test.txt /usr/local/etc/redis/test.txt`
but it works fine on version 18.03.0-ce. Which docker version are you using?

Comment: 18.03.1-ce-win65. Are you sure you're in windows mode?

Comment: I have the same issue in Docker for Windows (18.03.1) using Windows Containers and the  LCOW feature. Trying to find related bug reports for Docker but nothing seems to quite match.